# phpMyAdmin - Unable to UPDATE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

Ok, not used to working with queries in phpMyAdmin, but need to execute a query that looks like the following:

```
MERGE INTO `wp_posts` AS T
   USING `wp_postmeta` AS S
        ON (S.`post_id` = T.`ID` AND S.`meta_key` = '_thumbnail_id' AND (S.`meta_value` = 0 || S.`meta_value` = ''))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET T.`post_status` = 'private'
      WHERE T.`post_parent` = 0 AND T.`post_type` = 'product'
```

Problem is, I keep getting syntax errors from MySQL and can't find the problem.  Basically, what I want to be able to do here is `SELECT` all `post_id` values from the `wp_postmeta` table, WHERE `meta_key` = '_thumbnail_id' AND `meta_value` is either 0 or empty string.  THEN, I need to Update the `post_status` column to 'private' for all of these `post_id` values that match with the `ID` value in the `wp_posts` table, but also matching the `post_parent to 0 and`post_type` to 'product'.

How to do this with phpMyAdmin?

Also tried the following query:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
  SET `post_status` = 'private'
  WHERE `post_type` = 'product' AND `ID` IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND (meta_value = '0' || meta_value = ''));
```

When I run the above query, I get 0 rows affected, and it does not update anything.  If I run the query in the `IN` statement, I get a bunch of `post_id` values returned.  But it is not updating at all.  Why?

Another attempt at updating here:

```
UPDATE wp  
SET wp.`post_status` = 'private'
FROM `wp_posts` AS wp
    INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS wpm ON(wpm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` AND wpm.`meta_key` = '_thumbnail_id' AND (wpm.`meta_value` = 0 || wpm.`meta_value` = ''))
WHERE 
wp.`post_type` = 'product' AND wp.`post_parent` = 0;
```

None of these will work.  All syntax errors...  Last one gives me this syntax error, which I don't even understand:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'FROM `wp_posts` AS wp
>       INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS wpm ON(wpm.`post_id` = wp' at line 3

***EDIT***

Have changed that query directly above to look like this now:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` AS wp
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS wpm ON (wpm.`post_id` = wp.`ID` AND wpm.`meta_key` = '_thumbnail_id' AND wpm.`meta_value` = 0)
SET wp.`post_status` = 'private'
WHERE wp.`post_type` = 'product' AND wp.`post_parent` = 0;
```

Works, but am getting ***0 Rows Affected***  I don't understand why though...

Comment: I don't believe that MySQL supports `merge`.

Comment: How would I do this in myPhpAdmin than?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I soley refer to your last attempt:
Your update query is wrong. (This is also what the error states, there is no "from" option at this place)

If you want to update with a join, this is the syntax:

```
UPDATE tabelle1 AS a
JOIN tabelle2 AS b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.aktiv=1
WHERE xy like z
```

Comment: Thanks, updated my question with this syntax, I get 0 Rows affected... doesn't seem to be working. :(

Comment: i do not know the consistency of your db, therefore i suggest checking the string comparison.
please try the 'like' comparison:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Nothing works.  This is using Woocommerce plugin with Wordpress.  It is not changing the product to private, and does not change it in the database.  Strange.  I can the change the value of it manually in phpMyAdmin, but not with code for some strange reason!

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I got it, but I had to do the opposite of what I was doing!  Cheers and thanks for your help.  I basically set all products to private, and than updated only the ones with image ids to `publish`.  Looks great now!